# How to read data from docx file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, file, dart, docx, readfile

I have a local asset, a Docx file, (or in some cases only the UInt8List bytes), how is it possible to read the data from this file (or from bytes)?

This data contains only strings, how could I read it? I can read .txt file, but no docx, why?
In fact there is no special character in it, so the problem is not with the coding. (Check content below, HtmlCode)

I tried:
This is for the bytes

```
final data = await rootBundle.load('template.docx');
    final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
```

and
This is (would be) for the string

```
String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('template.docx');
```

Error:

```
Error: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 16)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:5366:11)
    at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertGeneral (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:49632:19)
    at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertSingle (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:49604:19)
    at Utf8Decoder.convert (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:49463:67)
    at Utf8Codec.decode (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:49172:22)
    at asset_bundle.PlatformAssetBundle.new.loadString (http://localhost:54436/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2289:31)
    at loadString.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:39272:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:39129:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:34091:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:34651:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:34689:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:34531:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:34554:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:39416:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:39422:13)
    at http://localhost:54436/dart_sdk.js:34905:9
```

There is no problem at all with the bytes, but with the string, this error will be thrown.
How could I solve this?

Full code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Html(),
    );
  }
}

class Html extends StatefulWidget {
  LoadHtml createState() => LoadHtml();
}

class LoadHtml extends State<Html> {

  void initState() {
    readFilesFromAssets();
    super.initState();
  }

// Read .docx function not only .docx mostly any type .json .txt etc
  readFilesFromAssets() async {
    print("read now");
    String assetContent = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/template.docx');
    print("assetContent : $assetContent");
  }

//this is exaclty what would be in the template.doc
  var HtmlCode = r"""
<HTML>
<BODY LANG="ru-RU" DIR="LTR">
<P CLASS="western" ALIGN=CENTER STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT FACE="Times New Roman, serif"><FONT SIZE=3><SPAN LANG="en-US">Example
Document</SPAN></FONT></FONT></P>
<P CLASS="western" ALIGN=CENTER STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"> <FONT FACE="Times New Roman, serif"><FONT SIZE=5><SPAN LANG="en-US"><B>Document
name</B></SPAN></FONT></FONT></P>
<P LANG="en-US" CLASS="western" ALIGN=CENTER STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">
<BR>
</P>
<P CLASS="western" ALIGN=CENTER STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT FACE="Times New Roman, serif"><FONT SIZE=3><SPAN LANG="en-US">Szerzodes
tobbi resze:</SPAN></FONT></FONT></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
    """;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('From docx')),
      body: WebViewX(
        initialContent: HtmlCode, //I should read this from the .docx
        initialSourceType: SourceType.HTML,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Pubspec and assets folder]

Comment: Have you added your `.docx` file in assets and also added a path of file inside `pubspec.yaml` like this `assets:
  – assets/myfile.docx`?

Comment: Yes, and I just tried to copy your code 1:1 to see if it works, but no, check my answer below in the comment
And I don't understand why, with .txt it works like a charm, but docx not.

Comment: Is `WebViewX` is inside webview_flutter package?

Comment: I don't know but your code is working fine I have duplicated it and it's running smooth.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx/
It's another package, it works on Web as well.
Hmm, interesting, for me it's not working, I use the latest flutter version.

Comment: Ok do like this. Delete your  .docx file and make a new one. Instead of adding content by opening word means don't open MS word to add content. Use notepad or sublime text to add content in your file and copy-paste your HTML code ok. Try like this. But its loading data but not showing on `WebViewX`

Comment: Ok I just tried to save a timple notepad file as docx, this way I can read the input. But as I said, it's a must to read it from a docx, because I have to apply some developer extension on this docx in Microsoft Word, which are impossible to add in pure texteditor.
Why can't I save a docx file in word and read it lol?

Comment: I get your point. The one thing I think of is `.docx` data have some security thing that prevents giving text of `.docx` file. I have no idea why this is happening xD Try to find other ways rather than my solution or any package you find on pub.dev will help.

Answer (score 1):

First add your `.docx` file inside the `assets` folder as same level with `lib` folder.
[image]

Then add your `assets` folder to `pubspec.yaml` like this

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

After than inside your `main.dart` add this function i.e `readFileFromAssets()` inside `initState()` to it will start loading data from `.docx` when app starts.

And import this package too `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

```
void initState() {
  readFilesFromAssets();
  super.initState();
}

// Read .docx function not only .docx mostly any type .json .txt etc
readFilesFromAssets() async {
  String assetContent = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/mytext.docx');
  print("assetContent : $assetContent");
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Yes I exactly do the same.

Have assets folder inside that my docx, pubspec.yaml also there

but still: 
below is my error:

Comment: ```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 16)
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1788:7)
#1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:318:42)
E/flutter (17417): #2      Utf8Codec.decode (dart:convert/utf.dart:63:20)
E/flutter (17417): #3      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:74:19)
E/flutter (17417): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17417): #4      LoadHtml.readFilesFromAssets (package:docxflutter/main.dart:373:27)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the
[Docs to text packages](https://pub.dev/packages/docx_to_text)

Readme
Changelog
Example
Installing
Versions
Scores
This is a small package that allows you to retrieve text (text only) from .docx files (Microsoft Word).

Thanks SnowLukin

```
Usage 
import 'package:docx_to_text/docx_to_text.dart';

final file = File('path/to/file.docx');
final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
final text = docxToText(bytes);
```